# "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)" when uploading file to FTP server in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am struggling to understand the concept on this error as I have the following information:

```
' Year (For Folder Name)
Dim Year As String
Year = Date.Today.Year
' Month (For Folder Name)
Dim Month1 As String
Month1 = MonthName(Month(Now()), False)
' Current Date (For File Name)
Dim todaysDate As String
todaysDate = Date.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")

Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest =
    DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(
        "directory" + Year + "\" + Month1 + "\" + todaysDate + ".csv"),
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password")
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
Console.WriteLine("Connected Successfully")

Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(
    "directory" + Year + "\" + Month1 + "\" + todaysDate + ".csv")

Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)
strz.Close()
strz.Dispose()
```

The error occurs on the following line:

```
Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
```

Error:

> The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g.,
> file not found, no access) VB.NET Error

All of the information that I have inputted is correct, I am just struggling to understand why this is error, as I have found this online and everyone else seems to recommend it. If anything could someone just explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

The argument of `WebRequest.Create` is an URL.

You are passing:

```
"directory" + Year + "\" + Month1 + "\" + todaysDate + ".csv"
```

That's clearly wrong.

1. It's not URL. The URL has to start `ftp://hostname`. Though I assume that you actually have the `ftp://hostname` there, as you would get a totally different error otherwise. *It's difficult to help you, if you are not showing us the real code.*
2. You have to use forward slashes.

The URL has to be something like:

```
"ftp://ftp.example.com/directory/" + Year + "/" + Month1 + "/" + todaysDate + ".csv"
```

Comment: Fixed it, it wasn't liking the fact I was creating sub directories within the location for some reason, strange but it's fixed the issue! Thank you for your help! :)